# How to change TD on this table using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to JQuery and I want to ask if anyone know how to loop to this table using JQuery, get the first row id and change the fifth TD data

```
<table id="thisTable">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="45215">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="78955">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance.

I'm researching everywhere, but seem to be very confuse.

Answer (score 1):

Inside loop using `$(this)` and `:last` pseudo you can change your `td` text.

Or using `:nth-child` find `td:nth-child(5)`  for 5th td and change your text.

Example:

```js
$('#thisTable > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
  // uncomment below line if you want to use nth-child
  // $(this).find('td:nth-child(5)').html("new td");
  $(this).find('td:last').html("new td");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thisTable">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="45215">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="78955">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr:first-child` to get the first `<tr>` and then use `.find('td:nth-child(5)')` to get the 5th `<td>` from this selected row.

```js
$("#thisTable tr:first-child").find('td:nth-child(5)').html("NEW TD");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thisTable">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="45215">
      <td>45215</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="45216">
      <td>45215</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>DONT Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="78955">
      <td>78955</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Change This TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```